# Django: How to setup Apache for a memory demanding application with very few users?

Tags: python, django, apache, postgresql

I am working on a very RAM demanding django application that is being used by a small set of users (concurrently 1-2 per day). The application is loading big BLOBs from postgreSQL and creates graphs. Each day, these BLOBs are getting bigger and bigger.

Now I am working on a Virtual Machine using 4 cores and 6 GB of RAM. And the application is not very fast. Also it is not very well built (I joined in very late and right now there is little time to optimize stuff).

Apache is working in prefork / Deamon mode.

```
~$ /usr/sbin/apache2 -V | grep MPM
Server MPM:     Prefork
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
```

and the size of each process is 0.5MB

```
$ ps aux | grep 'httpd' | awk '{print $6/1024 " MB";}'
0.589844 MB
```

This is my `Apache2.conf`

```
LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 100
KeepAlive Off
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          4
    MinSpareServers       4
    MaxSpareServers       8
    MaxClients           40
    MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>

User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
AccessFileName .htaccess
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>
DefaultType None
HostnameLookups Off
```

And this is my virtualhost:

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>                                                             
      ServerName example.com                                        
      ServerAlias example.com                                                    
      WSGIDaemonProcess example.com processes=4 threads=10 display-name=%{GROUP}
      WSGIProcessGroup example.com                                                       
      WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/project/wsgi.py              
     Alias /static/ /home/user/project/project/staticfiles/            
     <Location "/static/">                                                      
          Options -Indexes                                                       
     </Location>                                                                
      <Directory /home/user/project/>                                    
          AllowOverride None                                                     
      </Directory>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 </VirtualHost>
```

How to make Apache be as fast as possible?

Comment: I would start by installing Apache worker instead of prefork. mod_wsgi is multi threaded, so you don't need the prefork. Also, what kind of processing are you doing to the blobs? I don't think that you are going to do much with Apache to speed up your app.

Comment: There are timeseries objects in those BLOBs. I open them and create timeseries data analytics. So it is mainly "reading" not "writing". Writing happens at night in a separate processes.